# XLOOKUP using R

Tags: r, xlookup

I am trying to achieve XLOOKUP function from excel in R (as in attached picture). So far no luck with it. Any suggestion on this can be done in R Below is the code and example dataframe

```
dataF <- structure(list(
       A_1 = c(3.548393, 4.211518, 4.712385,3.895335,3.016505, 2.728305), 
       A_2 = c(3.879862, 4.061333, 4.950454, 4.242747,3.216443, 2.530415), 
       A_3 = c(6.543898, 8.928949, 9.418975, 8.372533,5.68308, 5.278409), 
       A_4 = c(3.493369, 4.108747, 4.477213, 3.256992,2.991532, 3.015297), 
       A_5 = c(3.548393, 4.211518, 4.712385, 3.895335,3.016505, 2.728305), 
       A_6 = c(7.428255, 8.272851, 9.662839, 8.138082,6.232948, 5.258721), 
       A_7 = c(10.09229, 13.14047, 14.13136, 12.26787,8.699586, 8.006714), 
       A_8 = c(13.64068, 17.35199, 18.84375, 16.1632,11.71609, 10.73502), 
       A_9 = c(17.46552, 21.31055, 23.55903, 19.76761,14.90756, 13.55243), 
       A_10 = c(21.01392, 25.52207, 28.27141, 23.66294,17.92407, 16.28073), 
       A_19 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), 
       A_20 = c(2L,2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
       A_21 = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), 
       SearchVal = c(2.5,2, 2, 2, 2.5, 3)),row.names = c(NA, -6L),class = "data.frame")

df_lookupVal <- tribble(~threshold,0,1,2,2.5,3,3.5)

dataF %>% mutate(New_Val = with(df_lookupVal, approx(df_lookupVal$threshold, 
                  dataF[,A_5:A_10], dataF[,SearchVal]))$y)
```

Expected output

```
> outputDF_with_newVariable$New_Val
[1] 13.64068 13.14047 14.13136 12.26787 11.71609 13.55243
```

XLOOKUP(SearchVal,df_lookupVal$threshold,dataF$A_5:A_10) - is there any easy way to realize this?

I tried it with approx but got some errors.

Comment: Could you explain what XLOOKUP does? I see the input data and the expected output but dont get what you wnat the code to do

Comment: You asked [essentially the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78220647/xlookup-vlookup-realization-in-r-dplyr) yesterday, which was closed because it lacked enough details to allow anyone to answer it. You were asked to edit the question to provide extra details, but instead you have posted the same question again without improving it. You have not even included the picture that you say you have attached. Please do not repost the same question.

Comment: Can you explain in words exactly what you are trying to do? Pretend Excel and xlookup don't exist (because in R, they don't exist). What are these `New_Val` values supposed to be?

Comment: I am attaching the picture but it is not shown in Stackoverflow...Also @Allan Cameron thanks I did also try to edit the question but it was closed for reply so  had to repost it. I think I have included what I have tried so far and also the actual data with desired output.

Comment: @MrFlick : Based on value at column SearchVal ; I try to find index from df_lookupVal$threshold and New_Val should be one of A_5:A_10 column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are trying to match up the values of SearchVal to the threshold column of df_lookupVal. The easiest way to do that in R is using `match()`. For example

```
match(dataF$SearchVal, df_lookupVal$threshold)
# [1] 4 3 3 3 4 5
```

That gives you the column that you want to extract. Because you are doing non-vectorized operations, when using `dplyr` you would have to use `rowwise()` here to extract values from different columns form each row. But that would look like

```
dataF %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(New_Val = c_across(A_5:A_10)[match(SearchVal, df_lookupVal$threshold)])
```

or with base R, you can create those values with

```
idx <- match(dataF$SearchVal, df_lookupVal$threshold)
dataF$New_Val <- dataF[, 5:10][cbind(seq_along(idx), idx)]
```